# Flutter Widget building & structure

Tags: flutter, dart

It seems there is a lots of way to build Widget in Flutter. It is a bit overwhelming to understand the right way of doing it. Can anyone explain me the difference between defining a variable inside/outside the build function as follow:

Inside class

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget {

 TextFormField username() {
  return TextFormField();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold();
 }

}
```

Inside build function

```
 class Login extends StatelessWidget {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 TextFormField username() {
  return TextFormField();
 }

 return Scaffold();

}
```

And also is there is any difference between defining the variable as follow:

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget {

 final username = TextFormField();

 TextFormField username() {
  return TextFormField();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold();
 }

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do anything within the programming world. With Flutter / Dart it would be no different.
However, there are more "orthodox" ways of doing things, which will certainly save you from structural problems.

1- Declaration of an instance.
When you have a class that is not a widget, you usually use common instances of classes.

```
String name = "Jonny";
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
```

When you declare widgets, there are 3 ways to do this, but only 1 is recommended.

The first is to store the widget in a variable (just like we did above).

```
final text = Text ('Pablo');
Build widget (BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold (body: text);
```

The second, and least recommended of all, is to create a method that gives you an instance of that widget

```
Widget text () {
return Text ('Pablo');
}

Build widget (BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold (body: text ());
```

This second approach is less recommended, because you will manufacture a new instance every time the method is called. If this widget has a heavy rendering, you are throwing resources in the trash.

The third (and highly recommended, I would tell you to stick to it and forget about it any other way) is nesting widgets in the tree:

```
Build widget (BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold (body: Text ('Pablo'));
```

This ensures that the same instance of Text () remains on the tree, and consequently if it were a much larger widget, this would be the most resource-efficient approach.

What if my tree becomes giant? how to avoid the ripple effect?
Simple, create new StatelessWidgets to break the tree's cascading effect.

```
Build widget (BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold (body: MyText());

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
Build widget (BuildContext context) {
return Container (child:
              Center (child: Text ('Pablo')),
       );
   }
}
```

Note: This was done for example purposes only, you must componentize reusable, or componentizable widgets, to avoid the effect:

```
  aa
    aaa
      aaaa
        aaaaa
          aaaaaa
           aaaaaaa
              aaaaaaa
```

But if you have a few lines of code you don't have to worry about it as much.